# how to override Pyramid's session factory?

Tags: pyramid

I'm trying to use both pyramid_persona and pyramid_beaker in the same project. However both are setting a session_factory in their `includeme()` method, and this leads to this error:

```
pyramid.exceptions.ConfigurationConflictError: Conflicting configuration actions
  For: <InterfaceClass pyramid.interfaces.ISessionFactory>
Line 173 of file /home/pyramid/project_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_beaker/__init__.py:
  config.set_session_factory(session_factory)
Line 50 of file /home/pyramid/project_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_persona/__init__.py:
  config.set_session_factory(session_factory)
```

I'm importing these modules in the `main()` method from  `__init__.py` like this:

```
config.include("pyramid_persona")
config.include("pyramid_beaker")
```

with pyramid v. 1.5.1, pyramid_beaker 0.8 and pyramid_persona 1.5.

Is there a way to tell Pyramid that it's ok to override the session_factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the session factory after including the addons by invoking `config.set_session_factory` yourself. Alternatively select the one you want and call `config.commit` between them. This is part of Pyramid's [conflict resolution mechanism](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/advconfig.html#manually-resolving-conflicts).